# Number of trees in bagged trees (random forest) model (matlab)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, bootstrap, matlab

I have trained a **Random Forest (bagged trees)** model in **matlab** using the **Classification toolbox**. Does anyone know how I can know the **number of trees** the model used?

In the code I saved from the training, this is the part where the parameters are defined, but the number of trees isn't specified:

```
template = templateTree(...
'MaxNumSplits', 65);
classificationEnsemble = fitcensemble(...
predictors, ...
response, ...
'Method', 'Bag', ...
'NumLearningCycles', 30, ...
'Learners', template, ...
'ClassNames', categorical({'A'; 'B'; 'C'; 'D'; 'E'}));
predictorExtractionFcn = @(t) t(:, predictorNames);
ensemblePredictFcn = @(x) predict(classificationEnsemble, x);
trainedClassifier.predictFcn = @(x) ensemblePredictFcn(predictorExtractionFcn(x));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Johanna, welcome to the site. This site does not solely focuses on programming questions.  Since this is a specific programming question, it might be helpful to post your question  In stackoverflow or directly on Matlab support website.

Comment: Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they use NumLearningCycles as the name of the parameter for the number of base models to use.  So in your case it is 30.

There is some documentation here for further review if needed!
https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitrensemble.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I had already read that whole document, and had failed to understand that NumLearningCycles was the number of trees in the model... thank you :)